# How to execute sql query with python variables null or empty

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I'm using python 3 and snowflake.
Example:

```
MY_SCHEMA = 'TEST'
MY_TABLE = Empty

sql = "SELECT SCHEMA, TABLE FROM TABLE_LOG WHERE SCHEMA = %s AND TABLE = %s"

tuple1 = (MY_SCHEMA, MY_TABLE)
cur.execute(sql,tuples1)
```

I tried with this:

```
 WHERE SCHEMA = %s OR (SCHEMA IS NULL AND %s IS NULL) also WHERE SCHEMA = IIF(%S IS NULL, SCHEMA, %s)
```

I'm getting TypeError: not enough arguments for format string. I would like to run this query for all schemas if I dont have defined MY_SCHEMA variable and also for all tables if MY_TABLE variable is null or empty.
I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Are you asking this for the sake of learning how it can be done, or are you actually planing to use this in productive code? Because handling this in Python (if..elif..else..) with 3 different statements is probably less "costly" than writing this as a single statement just to save a few lines of Python code and then having the sql server deal with inefficent sql.

Comment: @MikeScotty I will use this in production. From my sql output I creating pandas dataframe and then dictionary with schame name as keys and each schema has list of tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution this issue:

```
MY_SCHEMA = 'TEST'
MY_TABLE = None

cur.execute("SELECT SCHEMA,TABLE FROM TABLE_LOG WHERE SCHEMA = COALESCE(%(schema_variable)s,SCHEMA) AND TABLE = COALESCE(%(table_variable)s,TABLE )",{"schema_variable": MY_SCHEMA, "table_variable": MY_TABLE})
```